# Can you use a virtual credit card to withdraw money from an ATM in the UK?

Tags: uk, payment-cards, exchange, atms, mobile-apps

I'm contemplating getting a virtual credit card from a provider with more competitive exchange rates & fees for visiting the UK. The provider does support the popular smartphone payment apps, so it's possible to pay in (some) stores.

Can I withdraw GBP from a UK ATM this way, or do I need a physical card to withdraw money from an ATM?

---

In case it's relevant, the specific providers I have in mind are Revolut and Google Pay, but I'll be happy with any answer that says "it only works if you use so-and-so provider instead of those two".

Comment: It's funny that whilst reading the question I was going to make an answer about registering with Revolut to get their physical card, then topping up with your virtual card and using the physical one at the ATM. But once I read the whole message, it seems the virtual card itself you're using is Revolut's! Huh! In my day the virtual cards used to be something you would buy on a dodgy website which you could then either gift to people or use them yourself (for cases when your bank card didn't have online payment capabilities and you could get a virtual one using another payment method).

Comment: @kiradotee :) I am looking into pure virtual cards because for the next couple weeks I change addresses too often to risk having a physical card shipped.

Comment: Yes. I live in the UK and have a Revolut card which I use with no problem at all.

Comment: @terdon A physical Revolut card, yes, but you can't use a virtual Revolut card in an ATM.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few banks that allow you to withdraw from their **own** ATMs without a card (usually as an "emergency withdrawal service", with a code you get via telephone banking), but other than that, as far as I am aware, you most definitely need a physical card to withdraw from an ATM.

You may want to check out Transferwise. They can provide a real Mastercard that you can use in store and in ATMs, which is backed by their "borderless" account with competitive fees in many situations (though ATM withdrawals are free only up to £200 per month).

Comment: There are contactless cash machines but you need to have a current account with that bank and be using the card they issued/their smartphone app. e.g. Barclays https://www.barclays.co.uk/ways-to-bank/contactless-cash/

Comment: Accepting this answer because it answers the primary question, while Uciebila's answer adds a highly relevant partial workaround.

Comment: There are an increasing number of banks that are offering cardless withdrawals from their ATMs as a normal service rather, than as an emergency withdrawal service.

Comment: Technically, you need neither a physical card nor a smartphone app. More and more ATMs support contactless. If your bank supports Apple Pay, you should be able to withdraw with just your Apple Watch. For small amounts, even without a PIN.

Answer (score 29):

Alternatively to an ATM, you can ask for cashback in stores.

The way this works is that after scanning your items, you can ask the person at the till for cashback of X amount (normally smaller amounts work better as they might not have enough in the tills/the app of your choice might have a cap), they then add that to the purchase amount, charge the contactless payment (in this case Google Pay as you mentioned), and give you the money from the till.

I've done this *many* times before with Google and Samsung Pay without an issue, no physical card needed. The easiest place to do this is at chain stores such as Tesco, Lidl, Morrisons etc as they are very used to it and the large ones are open 24 hours a day.

Comment: But you would still need a physical card for this presumably? You can't pay in a shop with a virtual credit card.

Comment: @MJeffryes You can pay with any card loaded onto Samsung or Google pay, so you don't need a physical card at all for the process, and Google Pay is what the OP has in mind it seems, I'll edit to make this clearer!

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression that you can't get cashback with contactless, but I guess it depends on the card terminal and shop. Personally I wouldn't rely on it, but it's good to know.

Comment: Hard to rely on, would mean asking as shops if they accept it. I've tried where I live in some of the chains you've mentioned and they don't. Probably depends on the terminal they're using. Also cash back is usually £50 maximum so could get annoying while on travelling and bad if out of shopping hours.

Comment: +1 I do this in Tesco all the time, though have only tried with £10 or £20 so unsure how the larger amounts fair.

Comment: As it's missing from the answer, any kind of 'credit' card, vs a debit card (which is what I presume this virtual card would be) will generally charge for this service, whereas it's normally free on a debit card.

Comment: @djsmiley2k if OP is using Revolut's virtual card attached to Google Pay to pay using the phone then there's no additional charge from Revolut. Plus the transaction would probably be classified as a purchase and not ATM withdrawal but in either case Revolut has free allowances.

Comment: In store cashback is only available with a debit card, not a credit card.

Comment: Pretty sure this will only work with debit. Most/all stores will not give cashback for credit, the till won't even give the operator the option in most cases.

Comment: In the UK there would usually be no problem with asking for £50/£100 cashback.  The stores would *much* rather give you the notes to carry away than have to pay some expensive security guard to do it for them.

Comment: I yet to see a shop give cashback on a credit card as the shop is charged a % of the amount.   With a UK debit card the shop pays a  fee per transaction however much the transaction is.   (often none UK debit cards look like credit to the processing system shops use)

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that there is a limit to contactless payment. I believe it is £30 currently (from experience and some googling) so that would be a hard limit to how much cash you can get out in one go.

Comment: @Chris there's no limit for contactless using Apple Pay or Google Pay (because your transaction is protected by fingerprint/face unlock/PIN or password). You can spend £500 by taping your phone.

Comment: @kiradotee: Oh, interesting. I had assumed the restriction was in the contactless bit rather than something imposed by the card provider!

Comment: @kiradotee Many stores have a £30 limit on apple/google pay.  Tesco limit apple pay to try to encourage the takeup of their own payment app.  Last week I was at the ASDA petrol station in Brighton and there were large notices on the pumps warning about the £30 limit that they apply to apple pay.  I have seen similar in other places as well.

Comment: @uɐɪ I did a quick search and seems there's no limit BUT retailers can apply their own limits to Apple Pay and Google Pay. 

Comment: @uɐɪ, a 30 pound limit at the pump? What does petrol in the UK cost these days? That seems like a very low transaction limit.

Comment: @spuck - In Gloucester unleaded petrol is £1.219 a litre at the moment so yes £30 is a low limit for buying fuel.

Comment: @spuck Low depending on the area/car, most would put in about £40 or more, which is probably why they need the giant signs as everyone would be going over their set limit otherwise.... this coming from someone who uses their Samsung pay all over Glous/Merseyside for fuel 

Comment: I ended up trying cashback in 4-5 different store brands (can't remember for certain which ones,but I believe it was Co-op, Tesco, Sainsbury's, and M&S). Everytime I asked the cashiers before checkout, they said they don't offer cashback on Google Pay - but of course I don't know if that's due to general policy, technical restriction, policy at these specific stores, or incomplete training. This took place in various towns along the Welsh border.

Answer (score 4):

While the accepted answer is correct (I use a TransferWise card), the user specifically mentioned Revolut. Revolut provides a debit Mastercard (just like TransferWise) and I have used it across the EU (and in the UK...).

TransferWise may be available to users from more countries. My wife (Canadian, non-UK-resident) is not permitted a UK card, and uses *my* Revolut at UK ATMs, but she has a TransferWise account (I don't know if she could get a TransferWise debit card).

My favourite is Curve, because it charges back to a credit card, and I switch between my UK MasterCard and my Canadian Visa, depending where I am; and I never have to load it up like Revolut or TransferWise. The downside is that I *know* you can't get one of those if you are not a resident of the EEA.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed today that a self-service checkout in a Swedish supermarket, where you can pay with either card or cash, now had the option to withdraw money from it.

It's the first time I've ever seen it and I guess these could be found in the UK, maybe now maybe later. I know Tesco have self service machines that handle cash.

So if you are like me, living without a wallet, then those are a good and speedy option.

If you can't find any machines like these then your only options are to ask cashiers for a withdrawal, or to send money to someone you trust and ask them to withdraw it.

Comment: I've seen a few in the UK but it really depends on the type of store/branch/location as more often than not getting cashback from self service isn't widely available